# Bootstrap making a center div to contain site

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am nearing completion of my site http://csgoshack.com/shop/

I need to do one thing and this is to put a white box in the center of the screen so I am able to see the site.

I tried to do this by photoshoping a white box onto the background image but that didn't work.

How would I go about doing this?

```
.whitebg {
width: 1250px;
padding: 10px;
border: 1px solid black;
margin: 0;
background-color:#ffffff;
margin:auto;
position: absolute-center;
top:0;
}
```

Comment: under your main css stylesheet add .container { background-color:#fff;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you would need to **design your box using CSS** and call it in using HTML.

HTML:

```
<div class="body-content">Insert Lists, Text, and other body content here</div>
```

CSS:

```
.body-content {
    width:80%;
    height:80%;
    top:10%;
    position:absolute;
    background-color: white;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

Adjust the width, the height, the positioning, and the colors to your specifications. I wouldn't change the margin-left and right because **that centers the div inside of the body** ( unless you don't want it exactly centered ).

Hope this helped!

Comment: Hello, I have got this far with changing a few things around: http://csgoshack.com/shop/index.php?page=cats&id=18 

How would i make the top of the white box meet the nav bar and how would i make it so the nav bar always touches the bottom of the page!?

Also how would i make the background so i dont see the joins when i scroll and it stays static?

Thanks alot shaun.

Comment: You adjust how far it is from the top using `top:0;` and adjust the height to match it as well. Position set to absolute means it doesn't stay static on scroll, it moves.

Comment: I have changed the top bit and it dont seem to want to move the div.

See EDIT.

Comment: position: absolute-center isn't a recognized position.

Comment: It seems to of made mine work correctly when i change it back to absolute it moves it to the left.

Comment: Try changing it to position:absolute and center it using left:10%; or margin-left and right.